# how to prevent Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose from simply pasting first value in array

Tags: vba, transpose

So I am performing a relatively simple task in vba but scratching my head over the result. I write an array of coumn headers and then attempt to paste them via the Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose  function but am having no luck... it simply pastes the first value in the array the length of the range.

Here is my code:

```
<i>  sub test
     Dim myHeadings() As Variant
     Dim header_rng As Range

     myHeadings = Array("a", "b" , "C", "D")

     'Set header_rng = Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(10, UBound(myHeadings)))

     Dim name As String
     Dim name_Array As String
     name = TixCollection(1).ADR

     Call PrintArray(10, 2, myHeadings, name)


     End sub


     Sub PrintArray(RowPrint, ColPrint, ArrayName, WorkSheetName)

    'Dim element As Variant
    'For Each element In ArrayName
    'Debug.Print element
    'Next element


    Sheets(WorkSheetName).Range(Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint), _
    Cells(RowPrint, UBound(ArrayName))) = _
    WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrayName)

    End Sub
```

Whats wrong with this?

Comment: you are pasting the first value precisely because you transpose the array. Just remove the transpose bit. In addition, you probably want to tweak your Cells() bits as it won't work properly at the moment, so change `Sheets(WorkSheetName).Range(Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint), _
    Cells(RowPrint, UBound(ArrayName)))` to more like `With Sheets(WorkSheetName): .Range(.Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint), _
    .Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint + UBound(ArrayName) - LBound(ArrayName)))...:End With`

Comment: so instead of <i> Range = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrayName) I should just have Range = ArrayName?

Comment: yep. The array returned by Array() is an array of rank 1. In Excel, such 1-d arrays are treated as being a 'row' and not a 'column', if that makes sense. To put the data as a column, for instance, you would indeed use Range = Transpose().

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the array does not need to be transposed if you are looking to have headers be placed on the same row for difference columns.  However you need to add the number of Columns to the start column (2 in your case).  Here is the code that I got to work below.

```
Sub PasteHeadersToSheet()

    Dim myHeadings() As Variant
    myHeadings = Array("a", "b", "C", "D")

    ' set sheet name
    sheetName = "sheet1"

    ' set starting row
    startRow = 10

    ' set starting row
    startColumn = 2

    Call PrintArray(startRow, startColumn, myHeadings, sheetName)


End Sub


Sub PrintArray(RowPrint, ColPrint, ArrayName, WorkSheetName)

    ' set worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets(WorkSheetName)

    ' set starting cell
    Set cellStart = Cells(RowPrint, ColPrint)

    ' set ending cell
    Set cellEnd = Cells(RowPrint, UBound(ArrayName) + ColPrint)

    ' paste array to selected worksheet and range of cells
    ws.Range(cellStart, cellEnd) = ArrayName

End Sub
```